# Angular unit test verifying childcomponent's method call

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have a page with sidebar section with sidebar-component and content section with a page-component. From the page-component, when I click a button, the sidebar-component toggles. Below is the code,

```
  async onSidebarButtonPressed() {
    const sidebar = document.querySelector('#filter-sidebar');
    console.log(sidebar);
    (sidebar as any)?.toggle();
  }
```

Now I want to cover the scenario where the

> toggle()

is called. I tried stubing the sidebar-component,

```
  @Component({ selector: 'cf-wc-sidebar-filter-v9', template: '' })
    class SidebarStubComponent {
      toggle() { /* */}
    }
..
..
..


      it('should toggle sidebar action', async () => {
              const sidebarSpy= spyOn(document,'querySelector').and.callFake(()=>SidebarStubComponent);
   fixture.detectChanges();

  await component.onSidebarButtonPressed();

  });
```

I am getting an error "**_a.toggle is not a function**".
Initially I tried with state and the tech guys told not to use state for this. I tried with @ViewChild and it comes undefined. Since these 2 components are completely disconnected

How else can I test this scenario?

Comment: Querying the DOM directly is usually a code smell in Angular. One approach you could take here is to have a separate service to transmit the toggle message from  the pageComponent to the sidebar

Comment: OK. Is there any other way?

Comment: The other way I would try to do it is use an `@Output` on the pageComponent to send an event up to the page and sidebar's shared parent and when you receive that event, you modify a variable that is an `@Input` on the sidebarComponent. Beyond that it's a bit hard to comment without seeing more of the code

Comment: Side question, does `onSidebarButtonPressed` have to be `async`?

Comment: OK. Will try both the options. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm not necessary, I was using it for state action dispatch.